# JavaScript dynamic resize function in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the JavaScript Function that takes an overlaid absolute positioned video (that I've pre-cut) and resizes it based on the screen width. It works great.
I tried to refactor it into React, but it doesn't work anymore. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? I'm fairly new to React and think that I'm not using state the right way, but I can't wrap my head around how to define those consts and then change the width

This is the react component

```
class Cinema extends Component {
    state={
     standardHeight: 758,
     standardLeft: 520,
     background: document.getElementById("video"),
     overlay: document.getElementById("glass")
    }


    handleResize(){
      const { standardHeight, standardLeft, background, overlay} = this.state;
      overlay.style.display = "none"
      const backgroundWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth
        //var backgroundWidth = background.getBoundingClientRect().width;
      const backgroundHeight = background.videoHeight*backgroundWidth/background.videoWidth
        var newLeft = backgroundHeight*standardLeft/standardHeight;
        overlay.style.left = newLeft + "px";
        overlay.style.height = backgroundHeight + "px";
      overlay.style.display = "block";
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    const { background, overlay} = this.state;
    background.addEventListener('loadeddata', function() {
      this.handleResize();
    }); 
    window.addEventListener('load', async () => {
      let video = document.querySelector('video[muted][loop]');
      try {
        await video.play();
      } catch (err) {
        video.controls = true;
      }
      // Play overlay after 5 sec
      setTimeout(function() {
          overlay.play();
      }, 5000);
    });
    window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
      this.handleResize();
    });
  }

  render() {

    return (
        <div>
                <img src={housePic} alt="Cinema" />
                <video id="video" className={styles.video} src="https://aiimblabs.com/j/tree.mp4" muted autoPlay loop ></video>
                    <video id="glass" className={styles.glass} src="https://aiimblabs.com/j/dogy.mp4" muted autoPlay ></video>

            </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Cinema;
```

And here is the original JS function

```
// fallback: show controls if autoplay fails
// (needed for Samsung Internet for Android, as of v6.4)
var standardHeight = 758;
var standardLeft = 520;
var background = document.getElementById("video");
var overlay = document.getElementById("glass");

background.addEventListener('loadeddata', function() {
    resizeOverlay();
});
window.addEventListener('load', async () => {
  let video = document.querySelector('video[muted][loop]');
  try {
    await video.play();
  } catch (err) {
    video.controls = true;
  }
  // Play overlay after 5 sec
  setTimeout(function() {
      overlay.play();
  }, 5000);
});
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    resizeOverlay();
});

function resizeOverlay() {
  overlay.style.display = "none";
  var backgroundWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
    //var backgroundWidth = background.getBoundingClientRect().width;
  var backgroundHeight = background.videoHeight*backgroundWidth/background.videoWidth;
    var newLeft = backgroundHeight*standardLeft/standardHeight;
    overlay.style.left = newLeft + "px";
    overlay.style.height = backgroundHeight + "px";
  overlay.style.display = "block";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should not query elements directly using document.querySelector, you should use createRef instead 
Read more on the link below

https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Second, when registering function (no arrow functions) as handler for events
you must bind the context to the handler. when your handler is called, it is executed in a different context.

https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#how-do-i-bind-a-function-to-a-component-instance

Third, you should always remove the event listener you registered on componentDidMount hook, otherwise you will have performance issues and memory leaks

I refactored your component

```
class CustomVideo extends React.Component {


constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.videoRef = React.createRef();
    this.glassRef = React.createRef();

    this.state = {
      standardHeight : 758,
      standardLeft: 520,
    };

    this.handleResize = this.handleResize.bind(this);
  }

  handleResize() {
    console.log('should resize');
    const { standardHeight, standardLeft } = this.state;
    this.glassRef.current.style.display = 'none';
    const backgroundWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
    const backgroundHeight = this.glassRef.current.videoHeight * backgroundWidth / this.glassRef.current.videoWidth
    let newLeft = backgroundHeight * standardLeft / standardHeight;
    this.glassRef.current.style.left = newLeft + "px";
    this.glassRef.current.style.height = backgroundHeight + "px";
    this.glassRef.current.style.display = newLeft + "px";
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    this.videoRef.current.addEventListener('loadeddata', this.handleResize);
    this.videoRef.current.play();
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.handleResize);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.videoRef.current.removeEventListener('loadeddata', this.handleResize);
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.handleResize);
  }


  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <img alt="Cinema" />
        <video
          ref={this.videoRef}
          src="https://aiimblabs.com/j/tree.mp4"
          muted
          autoPlay
          loop>
        </video>
        <video
          ref={this.glassRef}
          src="https://aiimblabs.com/j/dogy.mp4"
          muted
          autoPlay
        >
        </video>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```